# Ruby gem for parsing country + city from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to determine the cities, states, and countries for twitter users.
The location field returns the location, but I need to parse it and store this data in a structured format.

For instance, if the location in an user's bio is "London", it should store the city as London, and the country as UK. If it's "Albany, NY", it should store the city as Albany, the state as NY, and the country as USA. If it's just "NY", it should store the state as NY, and country as USA.  If it's "India", it should store the country as India (with no city or state). Obviously if the location is nonsense like "outer space", it will return nothing.

Is there a gem out there that does something like this? If not, is there any way I can do this intelligently leveraging some 3rd party?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem to gelocalize twitter location. The best and free service i found is **openstreetmap**.

It is really easy to use and the response is JSON.

try yourself: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=london&format=json&&addressdetails=1&accept-language=en

Here the first element that match "london":

```
{
"place_id": "97592906",
"licence": "Data \u00a9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright",
"osm_type": "relation",
"osm_id": "65606",
"boundingbox": [
  "51.2867584228516",
  "51.6918754577637",
  "-0.510375142097473",
  "0.334015518426895"
],
"lat": "51.5072759",
"lon": "-0.1276597",
"display_name": "London, Greater London, England, United Kingdom",
"class": "place",
"type": "city",
"importance": 0.9654895765402,
"icon": "http:\/\/nominatim.openstreetmap.org\/images\/mapicons\/poi_place_city.p.20.png",
"address": {
  "city": "London",
  "county": "London",
  "state_district": "Greater London",
  "state": "England",
  "country": "United Kingdom",
  "country_code": "gb"
}
```

}

As you can see the `address` field contains all the informations you need.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Do u know if there any's rate limits for this?